# Adding skin to text input listener

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to add my skin to textInputListener in libgdx. I can add skin to dialog boxes but i couldn't find an example about textInputListener. My textInputListener code is below. I've tried different things to add skin but i've failed. Thanks for the answers.

```
Gdx.input.getTextInput(textInputListener = new TextInputListener() {

        @Override
        public void input(String text) {
          createUser(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void canceled() {

        }
    }, message, "");


}
```

Comment: Why you want an InputListener to have a Skin?

Comment: because i use skins for dialog boxes in my app. same design for all boxes should look good :)

Comment: What does InputListener have to do with Dialog boxes?

Comment: I'll create a new user name, i'm trying to make it with inputlistener, it opens something like a dialog box , input box, or the box that i can't name it :) i want to add a skin to that box.